# Datasheet View and Slow Query StackTrace-Managed

Tags: 2010, performance, datasheet, sql-query

I have a list with 20000 items when I'm trying to open it in Datasheet View it shows me 100 records and then alert on the screen.

> Cannot connect to the server at this time. You can continue working
>   with this list, but some data may not be available.

That specific list is wrong, I have also one with more than 80000 and works fine.

In Sharepoint logs I can see that error:

> Slow Query StackTrace-Managed:    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.OnPostExecuteCommand(SqlCommand
>   command, SqlQueryData monitoringData)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SqlSession.ExecuteReader(SqlCommand
>   command, CommandBehavior behavior, SqlQueryData monitoringData,
>   Boolean retryForDeadLock)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQueryInternal(Boolean
>   retryfordeadlock)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSqlClient.ExecuteQuery(Boolean
>   retryfordeadlock)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Library.SPRequestInternalClass.GetListItemDataWithCallback2(IListItemSqlClient
>   pSqlClient, String bstrUrl, String bstrListName, String bstrViewName,
>   String bstrViewXml, SAFEARRAYFLAGS fSafeArrayFlags,
>   ISP2DSafeArrayWriter pSACallback, ISPDataCallback pPagingCallback,
>   ISPDataCallback pPagingPr...  66538fd8-7a89-4740-954e-2bde46dcae0f

In deleveloper dashboard, that query is executing more that 80 seconds:

```
SqlCommand: 'DECLARE @DocParentIdForRF uniqueidentifier SELECT TOP 1 @DocParentIdForRF = Docs.Id FROM Docs WHERE Docs.SiteId = @SITEID AND Docs.DirName = @FDN AND Docs.LeafName = @FLN;      set nocount on;set ansi_warnings off;declare @aggrTable1 table(AggrNewID# uniqueidentifier, Count# int, GroupCol#0 nvarchar(255) COLLATE Polish_CI_AS); insert into @aggrTable1 select  NEWID() as AggrNewID#,COUNT(0) as Count#, t1.[nvarchar1] COLLATE Polish_CI_AS FROM UserData LEFT OUTER LOOP JOIN AllUserData AS t1 WITH(NOLOCK,INDEX=AllUserData_PK) ON (UserData.[int2]=t1.[tp_ID]) AND (UserData.[tp_RowOrdinal] = 0) AND (t1.[tp_RowOrdinal] = 0) AND ( (t1.tp_Level = 1) ) AND (t1.[tp_IsCurrentVersion] = CONVERT(bit,1) ) AND (t1.[tp_CalculatedVersion] = 0 ) AND (t1.[tp_DeleteTransactionId] = 0x ) AND (t1.tp_ListId = @L1) AND (UserData.tp_ListId = @L2) INNER MERGE JOIN Docs AS t2 WITH(NOLOCK) ON (UserData.[tp_RowOrdinal] = 0) AND (t2.SiteId=UserData.tp_SiteId) AND (t2.SiteId = @SITEID) AND (t2.ParentId = UserData.tp_ParentId) AND (t2.Id = UserData.tp_DocId) AND ( (UserData.tp_Level = 1) ) AND (t2.Level = UserData.tp_Level) AND (t2.IsCurrentVersion = 1) AND (t2.Level = 1 OR t2.Level =  2) WHERE ( (UserData.tp_Level = 1) ) AND (UserData.tp_SiteId=@SITEID AND (UserData.tp_ParentId=@DocParentIdForRF)) AND (UserData.tp_RowOrdinal=0) AND (t2.SiteId=@SITEID AND (t2.ParentId=@DocParentIdForRF)) GROUP BY t1.[nvarchar1] COLLATE Polish_CI_AS;set ansi_warnings on;set nocount off;SELECT t9.[MetaInfo], t7.* FROM (SELECT DISTINCT t3.[tp_ID] AS c11, t4.*, t5.[tp_Ordinal], t6.[nvarchar1] AS c11c12 FROM (SELECT TOP(@NUMROWS) t1.[tp_Created] AS c0c7, t2.[LeafName] AS c9, UserData.[tp_ContentTypeId], CASE WHEN DATALENGTH(t2.DirName) = 0 THEN t2.LeafName WHEN DATALENGTH(t2.LeafName) = 0 THEN t2.DirName ELSE t2.DirName + N'/' + t2.LeafName END  AS c4, UserData.[tp_Version], UserData.[tp_IsCurrentVersion], UserData.[nvarchar4], UserData.[tp_Created], UserData.[tp_HasCopyDestinations], UserData.[tp_ModerationStatus], UserData.[tp_Level], UserData.[tp_SiteId], UserData.[tp_CalculatedVersion], UserData.[nvarchar1], UserData.[nvarchar6], t1.[tp_ID] AS c0c6, t2.[ScopeId] AS c8, t2.[TimeCreated] AS c10, aggrTable#1.Count# AS __Count#1, t2.[SortBehavior] AS c3, t1.[nvarchar1] COLLATE Polish_CI_AS AS c0c1, UserData.[tp_HasAttachment], t2.[Type] AS c2, UserData.[tp_Modified], UserData.[tp_DeleteTransactionId], UserData.[tp_ParentId], UserData.[tp_DocId], UserData.[int2], UserData.[nvarchar3], UserData.[tp_ID], UserData.[tp_CopySource], UserData.[nvarchar5], aggrTable#1.AggrNewID# AS __AggrNewID#1, t2.[Id] AS c5, UserData.[nvarchar2], UserData.[int1] FROM UserData LEFT OUTER LOOP JOIN AllUserData AS t1 WITH(NOLOCK,INDEX=AllUserData_PK) ON (UserData.[int2]=t1.[tp_ID]) AND (UserData.[tp_RowOrdinal] = 0) AND (t1.[tp_RowOrdinal] = 0) AND ( (t1.tp_Level = 1) ) AND (t1.[tp_IsCurrentVersion] = CONVERT(bit,1) ) AND (t1.[tp_CalculatedVersion] = 0 ) AND (t1.[tp_DeleteTransactionId] = 0x ) AND (t1.tp_ListId = @L1) AND (UserData.tp_ListId = @L2) INNER MERGE JOIN Docs AS t2 WITH(NOLOCK) ON (UserData.[tp_RowOrdinal] = 0) AND (t2.SiteId=UserData.tp_SiteId) AND (t2.SiteId = @SITEID) AND (t2.ParentId = UserData.tp_ParentId) AND (t2.Id = UserData.tp_DocId) AND ( (UserData.tp_Level = 1) ) AND (t2.Level = UserData.tp_Level) AND (t2.IsCurrentVersion = 1) AND (t2.Level = 1 OR t2.Level =  2) INNER JOIN @aggrTable1 AS aggrTable#1 ON ((t1.[nvarchar1] IS NULL AND aggrTable#1.GroupCol#0 IS NULL) OR t1.[nvarchar1] COLLATE Polish_CI_AS=aggrTable#1.GroupCol#0) WHERE ( (UserData.tp_Level = 1) ) AND (UserData.tp_SiteId=@SITEID AND (UserData.tp_ParentId=@DocParentIdForRF)) AND (UserData.tp_RowOrdinal=0) AND (t2.SiteId=@SITEID AND (t2.ParentId=@DocParentIdForRF)) ORDER BY t1.[nvarchar1] COLLATE Polish_CI_AS  ASC ,UserData.[tp_ID]  ASC ) AS t4 LEFT OUTER JOIN UserDataJunctions AS t5 WITH(NOLOCK) ON (t4.[tp_SiteId] = t5.[tp_SiteId] AND t4.[tp_DeleteTransactionId] = t5.[tp_DeleteTransactionId] AND t4.[tp_IsCurrentVersion] = t5.[tp_IsCurrentVersion] AND t4.[tp_ParentId] = t5.[tp_ParentId] AND t4.[tp_DocId] = t5.[tp_DocId] AND t4.[tp_CalculatedVersion] = t5.[tp_CalculatedVersion] AND t4.[tp_Level] = t5.[tp_Level]) LEFT OUTER JOIN UserDataJunctions AS t3 WITH(NOLOCK) ON (t4.[tp_SiteId] = t3.[tp_SiteId] AND t4.[tp_DeleteTransactionId] = t3.[tp_DeleteTransactionId] AND t4.[tp_IsCurrentVersion] = t3.[tp_IsCurrentVersion] AND t4.[tp_ParentId] = t3.[tp_ParentId] AND t4.[tp_DocId] = t3.[tp_DocId] AND t4.[tp_CalculatedVersion] = t3.[tp_CalculatedVersion] AND t4.[tp_Level] = t3.[tp_Level]) AND (t5.[tp_Ordinal] = t3.[tp_Ordinal]) AND (t3.[tp_FieldId] = @L7) LEFT OUTER LOOP JOIN AllUserData AS t6 WITH(NOLOCK,INDEX=AllUserData_PK) ON (t6.[tp_ListId] = @L8) AND (t6.[tp_Id] = t3.[tp_ID]) AND (t6.[tp_RowOrdinal] = 0) AND (t6.[tp_IsCurrentVersion] = CONVERT(bit,1) ) AND (t6.[tp_CalculatedVersion] = 0 ) AND (t6.[tp_DeleteTransactionId] = 0x ) AND ( (t6.tp_Level = 1) )) AS t7 LEFT OUTER JOIN Docs AS t9 WITH(NOLOCK) ON (t9.[SiteId] = t7.[tp_SiteId] AND t9.[DeleteTransactionId] = t7.[tp_DeleteTransactionId] AND t9.[ParentId] = t7.[tp_ParentId] AND t9.[Id] = t7.[tp_DocId] AND t9.[Level] = t7.[tp_Level] ) ORDER BY t7.c0c1 COLLATE Polish_CI_AS  ASC ,t7.tp_ID  ASC ,t7.[tp_Ordinal]  ASC  OPTION (FORCE ORDER, MAXDOP 1)'
   CommandType: Text CommandTimeout: 0
   Parameter: '@LFFP' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
   Parameter: '@L1' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: 'a36960d9-aeb5-49af-86e3-04bf61c3c8c0'
   Parameter: '@L2' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '451893ed-6f60-4fbe-8248-5412c65d3004'
   Parameter: '@SITEID' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '4c52f123-8850-4946-86c1-4235210df404'
   Parameter: '@FDN' Type: NVarChar Size: 4000 Direction: Input Value: 'Lists'
   Parameter: '@FLN' Type: NVarChar Size: 4000 Direction: Input Value: 'Pakiety lekw'
   Parameter: '@NUMROWS' Type: BigInt Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '101'
   Parameter: '@L7' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: 'a1950602-1cdd-45bf-8579-cc1882f58a35'
   Parameter: '@L8' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '183396a3-4878-4da2-a839-983f6a119977'
   Parameter: '@RequestGuid' Type: UniqueIdentifier Size: 0 Direction: Input Value: '2bff3cea-a473-4461-9fcd-9756e2ad1d32'
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't expect SharePoint to work well opening any view with more that 2000/5000 items (depending on SQL server version).

What may slow it further down is:

- Lookup columns (including User and Managed Metadata)
- Many columns of certain type causing SharePoint to use multiple rows in SQL for each item

Many is defined as:

64 Single line of text
32 Multiple Lines of Text
64 Choice
12 Number
12 Currency
8 Date and Time
6 Lookup
16 Yes / No
16 Person or group
32 Hyperlink or picture
8 Calculated
16 Int